# Result NaN when parameter Date.UTC was defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two case.

case 1:`Date.UTC(2008,9,6);`

case 2:

```
var a = '2008,9,6';
Date.UTC(a);
```

with case 1 will show result true is timestamp but case 2 will be NaN

Anybody can explain and give me solution for case 2.

Thanks!

Comment: **Case 1:** you are passing three parameter (year, month, day) => valid. **Case 2:** you are passing one parameter which is a string => not valid!

Comment: You can use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) like this: `Date.UTC.apply(null, a.split(','));`!

Comment: `2008,9,6` is not a number, it's NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case1**

```
Date.UTC(2008,9,6);
```

You are passing three different parameters to UTC function which are numbers YEAR, MONTH, DAY

**Case2**

```
var a = '2008,9,6';
Date.UTC(a);
```

You are passing only 1 parameter which is a string which is invalid.
As per documentation the first parameter that UTC function takes is YEAR, therefore **YEAR** cannot be equal to **"2018,9,6"**

To fix this you can do

```
Date.UTC('2008','9','6')
```

For further reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp